# Given a sorted array find number of all unique pairs which sum is greater than X

Tags: arrays, sorting, big-o, combinations, complexity-theory

Is there any solution which can be achieved with complexity better than
O(n<sup>2</sup>)? Linear complexity would be best but O(nlogn) is also great.

I've tried to use binary search for each element which would be O(nlogn) but Im always missing something.

For example, given the sorted array: `2 8 8 9 10 20 21`
and the number X=18
`[2,20][2,21][8,20][8,21][8,20][8,21][9,10][9,20][9,21][10,20][10,21][20,21]`
The function should return 12.

Comment: why it should return 12?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi You'd guess that there are 12 pairs whose sum is greater than 18. I've not checked :-)

Comment: i think answer should be 11. _{2,20},{2,21},{8,10},{8,20},{8,21},{9,10},{9,20},{9,21},{10,20},{10,21},{20,21}_

Comment: @DeepakTripathi since when would 8,10 give you a sum greater than 18? I guess if "unique pairs" is a phrase which allows one of the 8s to be ignored, then the number changes. Assumed not since 12 was given as the answer, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Sorry ,i meant unique index wise, hence: [2,20][2,21][8,20][8,21][8,20][8,21][9,10][9,20][9,21][10,20][10,21][20,21]

Comment: Rearranging gives your example output gives you the answer: All those combinations involving 21. All the combinations of 20, except the already-listed combination with 21. All the combinations of those numbers which can be involved in a sum above your value, which is all of the combinations of 9...10.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, for any given set of numbers, there may be some which, included with any other number, are guaranteed to be a solution because in themselves they are greater than the target amount for the summing.

Identify those. Any combination of those is a solution. With your example-data, 21 and 20 satisfy this, so all combinations of 21, which is six, and all remaining combinations of 20, which is five, satisfy your requirement (11 results so far).

Treat your sorted array now as a subset, which excludes the above set (if non-empty).

From your new subset, find all numbers which *can* be included with another number in that subset to satisfy your requirement. Starting from the highest (for "complexity" it may not matter, but for ease of coding, knowing early that you have none often helps) number in your subset, identify any, remembering that there need to be at least two such numbers for any more results to be added to those identified.

Take you data in successive adjacent pairs. Once you reach of sum which does not meet your requirement, you know you have found the bottom limit for your table.

With this sequence:

```
1 2 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

19 already meets the criteria. Subset is of nine numbers. Take 18 and 17. Meets the criteria. Take 17 and 16. Meets. 16 and 15. Meets... 13 and 12. Meets. 12 and 2. Does not meet. So 12 is the lowest value in the range, and the number of items in the range are seven.

This process yields 10 and 9 with your original data. One more combination, giving your 12 combinations that are sought.

Determining the number of combinations should be abstracted out, as it is simple to calculate and, depending on actual situation, perhaps faster to pre-calculate.

A good rule-of-thumb is that if you, yourself, can get the answer by looking at the data, it is pretty easy for a computer. Doing it the same way is a good starting point, though not always the end.

---

Find the subset of the highest elements which would cause the sum to be greater than the desired value when paired with *any* other member of the array.

Taking the subset which excludes those, use the highest element and work backwards to find the lowest element which gives you success. Have that as your third subset.

Your combinations are all those of the entire group for members of the first subset, plus solely those combinations of the third subset.

You are the student, you'll have to work out how complex that is.

Comment: Because 18 17 (going backwards from 18) is a pair, 18 16 is a pair and so on until 18 1. But 17 16 is also a pair and so on until 17 2... And so on until 15 14. That's n^2 in the worst case.(you could think of even worse case examples than this one, where you have to go through all the elements).

Comment: OK, I've clarified. That's my mistake as well, if not clear. Clearing the comments do (clix on the x-in-a-circle which appears when you mouse-over your own comments).

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much, but there is a problem with the array : -100 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 6 7,  X=5. When i check the sum of the  adjacent pairs, the last one should be [2,3] and the range is 3, but [4 2] and [4 2] also meets the demand, and i can't reach [2 1] to limit the range to from 2 to 4 because the check stops at [2 3].

Comment: Don't worry about whether it is a bother. I stuck my oar in by choice :-) . There are two subsets analagous to those already identified. But. The -100 item breaks the premise about 21/20 being able to combine with all.  Can lead to a better way. Take the smallest index, and test until true, or array exhausted. If true, calculate how many combinations remain. Continue with the next smallest. Continue until you reach the first adjacent pair which are true, then just calculate the rest. No time now to write it up.